# Bring a Dynamic Text Field to the Front (w/o using a MovieClip)

Tags: flash

I searched google but nothing. I am guessing that either you can't do it or there is a way to do it other than the child functions.

I have an enemy box setup like

-container
--background
--text
-enemy movieclip

So I have a MovieClip box with a text field on it with the instance name, say, textSpot. It is not a MovieClip but a regular drag and drop text field. Reordering would be a pain. I am wondering if there is a way to get the text to the front, as when adding the enemy movieclip, it covers the text.

So is there a way to bring something to the front that does not exist in the library, and only have an instance name? Otherwise, if not possible, would I just make a container for the text, and then use the normal setChildIndex() to set to front?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that an element is or isn't in the library as no impact at all on whether or not it can be ordered. As long as an object is a `DisplayObject`, it can be added to a `DisplayObjectContainer` and thus be target of `setChildIndex()`.

Both `MovieClip` and `TextField` are DisplayObject, but only MovieClip is a DisplayObjectContainer. In other words, you can add both MovieClips and Textfields as children, but only MovieClips can contain children.

So, it is possible to use `setChildIndex()` on a `TextField`.

However, from the setup you've indicated, *text* is a child of *container* and not *enemy*. That will be a problem. `setChildIndex()` can only be used to reorder elements with the same parent. So to be able to place *text* on top of *enemy*, you'll have in fact to place *container* on top of *enemy*... and that includes background. If you want your texts to be on top of your enemies, you'll have to move them out of container, possibly with a setup (from example) like that :

```
stage
  foregroundLayer <== a MovieClip on top of the "scene", that contains the Texts
    text1
    text2
  enemyLayer <== a MovieClip that contains all the enemies.
    enemy1
    enemy2
  backgroundLayer <== Your actual "container"
    background
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. With this I was able to bring the text to the front of the container movieclip's.

enemyButton[i].setChildIndex(enemyButton[i].getChildByName("enemyName"), enemyButton[i].numChildren-1);